# ARKit How to hide X Y Z world origin anchor?

Tags: arkit

I want to delete those world origin anchor(?) ...I published app but it still appear on screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The world origin you are referring to is part of the `ARSCNDebugOptions` which are:

> options for drawing overlay content to aid debugging of AR tracking in
>   a SceneKit view.

Specifically what you are referring to is the `.showWorldOrigin` parameter which:

> displays a coordinate axis visualization indicating the position and
>   orientation of the AR world coordinate system.

As such, one way to disable this is as follows:

```
augmentedRealityView.debugOptions = []
```

Whereby augmentedRealityView is an `ARSCNView`.

Hope it helps...